# How to place footnotes on the same page as the reference in LaTeX?

Tags: lists, footnotes, description

I'm encountering an issue while writing a LaTeX document where I have a list with references, each accompanied by a corresponding footnote. However, after compiling the document, I've noticed that the footnotes are all appearing on the last page of the chapter, where the list ends, instead of on the same page as their respective references.

The list extends over three pages due to its length. Despite attempting to ensure the footnotes appear on the same page as their references, I haven't been successful.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem? Thank you!

```
\section{Websites Overview}

A list of the websites found with a short description is shown below.

\begin{description}
    \item[\textbf{Website A\footnotemark[1]}:] \hfill \\
    Website A description.

    \item[\textbf{Website B\footnotemark[2]}:] \hfill \\
    Website B description.

    \item[\textbf{Website C\footnotemark[3]}:] \hfill \\
    Website C description.

    \item[\textbf{Website D\footnotemark[4]}:] \hfill \\
    Website D description.

    \item[\textbf{Website E\footnotemark[5]}:] \hfill \\
    Website E description.
\end{description}

\footnotetext[1]{Available at \url{https://websitea.com}, visited on 02/15/2024}
\footnotetext[2]{Available at \url{https://websiteb.com}, visited on 02/15/2024}
\footnotetext[3]{Available at \url{https://websitec.com}, visited on 02/15/2024}
\footnotetext[4]{Available at \url{https://websited.com}, visited on 02/15/2024}
\footnotetext[5]{Available at \url{https://websitee.com}, visited on 02/15/2024}
```

Answer (score 1):

write the text directly into the item. There is no need for manual numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Websites Overview}

A list of the websites found with a short description is shown below.

\begin{description}
    \item[\textbf{Website A\footnotemark}:]
    \leavevmode\footnotetext{Available at \url{https://websitea.com}, visited on 02/15/2024} \hfill \\
    Website A description.

    \item[\textbf{Website B\footnotemark}:]
    \leavevmode\footnotetext{Available at \url{https://websiteb.com}, visited on 02/15/2024} 
    \hfill \\
    Website B description.
\newpage % test new page ...
    \item[\textbf{Website C\footnotemark}:] 
    \leavevmode\footnotetext{Available at \url{https://websitec.com}, visited on 02/15/2024} \hfill \\
    Website C description.

    \item[\textbf{Website D\footnotemark}:] 
    \leavevmode\footnotetext{Available at \url{https://websited.com}, visited on 02/15/2024} \hfill \\
    Website D description.

    \item[\textbf{Website E\footnotemark}:] 
    \leavevmode\footnotetext{Available at \url{https://websitee.com}, visited on 02/15/2024} \hfill \\
    Website E description.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked well :)